# Prevent macOS Messages.app from quitting when I close its window?

Tags: macos, mac, dock, mojave

I use a very specific workflow with the Messages app on the Mac:

1. Read my messages
2. Close the Messages *window* with <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>
3. Messages *app* is still running
4. When a new message comes in, <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the still-open Messages app
5. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> to [re-open the Messages window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264859/when-using-cmd-tab-how-to-re-open-the-apps-main-window)

After closing the Messages window, the app has always remained open and running in the Dock and app switcher.

[image: Messages window closed, but App still running]

In Mac OS 10.14 Mojave, I similarly close the Messages window. After closing the Messages window, the Messages app is still in the foreground, running, and shows the menu bar.

When I click to some other app, however, the Messages app then immediately seemingly *Quits*.

The dot disappears from the dock, and (this is the key issue) I can no longer <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the Messages app in the app switcher.

[image: App has closed; no Dock dot]

I'm forced to go click the dock icon with my mouse or otherwise re-open the app, which is inconvenient and annoying.

After the app has Quit, besides being "Quit", it seems to behave more-or-less exactly how it used to behave pre-Mojave. The Messages process is still running and visible in Activity Monitor. Notifications continue to arrive. The dock icon gets badged.

[image: Activity Monitor]

How do I prevent Messages from quitting when I close its window?

> rdar://46142132 - Mojave Messages.app should not quit when I close its window
>
> Engineering has determined that your bug report (46142132) is a duplicate of 42085189 and will be closed.

Related links:

- [With Mojave (macOS 10.14), why does the Message app close itself?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338988/with-mojave-macos-10-14-why-does-the-message-app-close-itself)
- [Messages app now quits when close window?](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/messages-app-now-quits-when-close-window.2142561/)
- [Messages app quits on Mojave instead of closing](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/9lpagb/messages_app_quits_on_mojave_instead_of_closing/)

Comment: I'm not in front of a Mojave machine at the moment to test if your workflow produces the same results at my end, but in the meantime at Step 2 of your workflow is there a reason why *minimising* the window instead of closing it wouldn't be a good option? I'll be able to test Mojave in the next hour though and will let you know what happens for me.

Comment: I think the only difference is cosmetic? I still get new message notifications regardless of whether the dock says it is open or closed.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy In a mouse or notification-driven usage pattern it may be somewhat "cosmetic", but the app being removed from the CMD-Tab menu is a major functional change.

Comment: Ok, I've tested this at my end and the Messages app continues running for me even when I've closed the Messages window with the `CMD`-`W` shortcut. And, when I test your entire workflow it works fine for me. As a test, how about going through the process so that you've closed the Messages window and the Messages app icon disappears from the Application Switcher, but is still visible in Activity Monitor. Wait a few mins and then send a message to yourself from an other one of your devices (e.g. an iPhone). Does the Messages app on the Mac register that it's received a message?

Comment: @Monomeeth just added another detail: after CMD-W, the menu bar still belongs to Messages and the app stays open while still in focus. But click on any other open app/window, and THEN messages quits. That might help you reproduce.

Comment: I've actually already tested for that. :) What I'm interested in now is the behaviour at your end once the Messages app seems to quit. Does it still remain in Activity Monitor even a few minutes later, and does it still receive messages if you (or someone else) sends you one while it's in the *Quit* state?

Comment: @Monomeeth Edited post. Yes, the process continues to run indefinitely. New messages are delivered and the dock icon badged. Only the user-facing "app" is being quit, the backend is still fully functional.

Comment: Ok, so the only behaviour that's really different is that the App itself doesn't appear in the Application Switcher **and** the dot disappears from the icon in the Dock, but everything else works okay?

Comment: Oh, and forgive the obvious question, but have you tried rebooting your Mac to see if this fixes the issue?

Comment: @Monomeeth Restart doesn't fix. I'm surprised to hear you cannot reproduce this. This appears to be the new behavior in Mojave. Other threads around the web as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85860/discussion-between-monomeeth-and-pkamb).

Comment: I also use this workflow, except cmd-0.  This automatic termination, which is also how Photos behaves is a strange, divergent UX for MacOS. I do not know how Apple decides which apps to do this with, and I think it was pretty lame to just change this behavior with no notification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I can see that's just another case of "[Automatic Termination](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH3-SW14)", similar to Preview, QuickTime Player, etc.

If you launch Terminal (from /Applications/Utilities/) and run the following command with Messages quit, Messages should stop terminating, when the window is closed:

`defaults write com.apple.iChat NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool yes`

Then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

To undo it again:
`defaults delete com.apple.iChat NSDisableAutomaticTermination`

Comment: This works! Thank you. I was having no success from similar answers that suggested `NSSupportsAutomaticTermination`. But `NSDisableAutomaticTermination` for the specific process does seem to disable the behavior.

Comment: @pkamb Instead of it being application specific (com.apple.iChat), you should also be able to disable it globally with the same command, but using `-g` instead of `com.apple.iChat`.

Comment: This works, key detail is Messages must be fully quit before the command is run. It should work once you restart Messages after.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a strange one since it appears only to be affecting the Messages app **and** the Messages app appears to actually still be running in the background. Add to that the fact that I can’t reproduce it at all.

I have two *potential* solutions for you to try. You do not need to try these in any particular order - try one first and if the issue returns, then try the other.

**Option 1: Reset and restart the Dock**

One remedy is to reset **and** restart the Dock. However, in doing so, **you will need to re-add any non-default icons to your Dock**. (I usually find it's a good opportunity for people to start afresh and only add things as they actually use them).

You can reset and restart the Dock as follows:

- Go to Finder
- Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down
- Now go to the Go menu
- Select the Library option to open the User's *Library* folder. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now.
- Go to the Preferences folder (i.e. within the Library folder)
- Find and move the **com.apple.dock.plist** file to the Trash
- Now open Terminal (usually located in Applications > Utilities)
- Enter this command `killall -KILL Dock`
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Remember you'll need to re-add some apps back to the Dock.

**Option 2: Reset icon cache**

You can also try resetting the icon cache.

- Launch Terminal (usually found in the Applications > Utilities folder)
- Enter the following three commands, one at a time:

  ```
  sudo find /private/var/folders/ \ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
  sudo find /private/var/folders/ \ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
  ```

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Besides a Dock issue, this might be an AppNap issue or a LaunchServices issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Redarm` might work for iChat, but if you want this to have affect for other apps you can do the following just as simply by executing this command in the Terminal:

`defaults write -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool TRUE`

I tried `Redarm`'s answer on macOS Catalina and it failed to work; closing the window still completely quit the Messages app. After I run my command (above) it worked perfectly!