# Mojave's changes to application states

Tags: applications, mail.app, messages, window-manager, messages-in-icloud

Before I upgraded to Mojave, there were two Apple applications that remained open after I would close them. Now, their behavior has changed quite a bit.

The applications are Mail and Messages.

Until Mojave, if I closed the window of either Mail or Messages, then the application would remain open in the background, with the dot on the dock indicating so. Since upgrading, if I close the window of Messages and click on another application's window, the Messages application **quits itself** and I won't receive notifications again until I relaunch the application.

Also, if I close the inbox window of the Mail application, it will later reopen itself sporadically throughout the day (not prompted by incoming messages), sometimes compromising my Mac's ability to perform/prioritize tasks (for example, when I had my preferences set to use a side-by-side view for Mail when my system was in full-screen, it would cause video to glitch out and suddenly occupy half of my screen with a Mail window).

Is there any way I can change this so that both applications remain in the background when their windows are closed? I'm open to any level of coding necessary to accomplish this.

Note: I do have a Gmail activated in Mail. It has occurred to me that this may be what keeps reopening the window to check for new messages periodically, but I am not certain.

Comment: Regarding Messages see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342893/prevent-macos-messages-app-from-quitting-when-i-close-its-window/342968#342968

Comment: Re Mail - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352044/mail-opens-a-window-randomly-in-split-screen-with-my-fullscreen-window & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344223/mail-app-keeps-popping-up-in-the-background-in-mac-os-mojave

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, but the solutions offered do not work. When I close an app that then remains open, it gets pushed to the back end of the application switcher (command+tab), but when I merely hide or minimize (as proposed in the answers to the questions you shared), it remains in the second slot. Is there, perhaps, a way to force minimized apps to be pushed to the end of the application switcher?

Comment: Sorry, it's not a workflow I'm familiar with. I don't use fullscreen, splitscreen or use Cmd/Tab to switch apps. I use lots of Spaces & have apps pinned to each - that way I can use Ctrl/(number) to go to any app. I never need to close or minimise windows that way.